# Link in popup page not working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension to bookmark pages and store them as JSON with localStorage.
Here's a screenshot -
[image: Extension screenshot]
The problem is that when I click on the link, nothing happens.
So I tried to assign all the links a .link class, and attached this listener -

```
$('.link').click(function(){
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  var urlList = {};
  urlList['url'] = url;
  chrome.tabs.create(urlList);
});
```

But still nothing happened. I did right click on browser action button and tried inspect popup and it shows that there is no listener attached to the link.

Here is [source of whole project](https://github.com/saivineet89/DocSaver) on github.

Please help me make this link open a new tab with the specified url.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the right url address in href property of your links. Thus, in you `$('#viewAll').click(function(){ ... }` callback, replace the line

```
str += '<tr>' + '<td><a class="link" href="' + objects[keys[i]] + '">' + keys[i] +
```

by

```
str += '<tr>' + '<td><a class="link" href="http://' + keys[i] + '">' + keys[i] +
```

And it will work!

Comment: I just tried it and it worked! Double check if you didn't do any typo.

Comment: Also, observe I added "http://" before the actual url. Without it, it's not gonna work.

Comment: Now its opening a new tab, but the http:// is becoming http// and no typos , I checked it twice now.

Comment: Very strange. It's really working here. What's your Chrome version and OS? It must be a very odd environment quirk.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 32bit chrome 25

Comment: ok, problem solved! I removed all http:// s and the address now doesn't have a http:// but it still works! Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you replaced the line 45 exactly with the code I wrote or you just made the adjustments manually?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25352/discussion-between-vineet-and-saul-berardo)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have done some changes in [your code](https://github.com/saivineet89/DocSaver/blob/master/popup.js)

```
$('.link').live('click', function() {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#message').html(url);
  chrome.tabs.create({ 'url' : url });
});

$('#viewAll').click(function(){
  var objects = JSON.parse(localStorage['DocSaver'])

  var keys = [];
  for (key in objects) {
    keys.push(key);
  }
  var i = 0;
  var keyslen = keys.length;
  var str = '';
  //SORTED KEY ITERATION
  while (i < keyslen) {
    str += '<tr>' + '<td><a class="link" href="' + objects[keys[i]] + '">' + keys[i] +
    '</a></td></tr>'
    ;
    ++i;
  }
  $('#viewFrame > table').html(str);
  $('#viewFrame').css('display','block');
  $('#message').html('Done displaying!');
});
```